# install whitelist of packages using unstable in debian

Tags: debian, installation, packages

i want to just some packages installation from unstable version of debian.

```
apt-get -t unstable install myspecialpackage
```

but when i

```
apt-get upgrade
```

it will wanting to download some packages from unstable.

also i added this line /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

what's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pinning and set all unstable packages to a pinning value below 500, and add pinning values above those for stable (normally 500, but 990 if `APT::Default-Release` is used) for those unstable packages you want:

Example `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 110

Package: myspecialpackage
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 991
```

(I can't remember if the order actually matters. If so, reverse the two paragraphs.)

Have a look in the `apt_preferences(5)` man page for the details.